# Operators in C#: Is there something like the "IN" operator in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, operators, code-behind

I've got this statement in a C# code-behind where I'm checking to see if my variable is equal to a specific number, and if so it will process some code:

```
try
{
    int TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTask.SelectedValue);

    if (TaskID == 157)
    {
         //lblAccountName.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString());
         Label2.Text = (DT1["CUST_NM"].ToString());
         //lblAccountName.Visible = true;
         TBAccountNum.Text = (DT1["CUST_NUM"].ToString());
         TBAccountNum.Visible = true;
     }
}
catch (Exception ae)
{
     Response.Write(ae.Message);
}
```

Works perfect.  However, now I want to add a few other numbers to that "if" list.  In SQL Server it would go something like:

```
if (TaskID IN (157, 158, 159, 160, 162, 165))
```

Is there any way to do this in C#?  I'm still learning, so I apologize if this is a bit simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just write :

```
if ( new int[]{157, 158, 159, 160, 162, 165}.Contains(TaskID))
    ....
```

Don't forget to add the following reference :

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to specify the type of the array as it can be inferred (`new[] {...` vs `new int[] {...`).

Comment: Both this and svick's answers were perfect, I gave this one the check because it was a little more complete.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use a collection (e.g. an array) of items together with [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118) from LINQ:

```
new[] { 157, 158, 159, 160, 162, 165 }.Contains(TaskID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `switch` statement, which will allow other possibilities:

```
switch (taskId)
{
    case 175:
    case 176:
    case 177:
        // code for any of the values above
        break;

    case 200:
        // yet another possibility
        break;

    default:
        // any other value
        break;
}
```